# Convert from PHP array(array()) to CF

Tags: php, coldfusion

And how I can convert this to CF

```
  $client = array( array( "apPat" => 'Estrada', "apMat" => 'Castillo' ) );
```

I need to send this object to net webservice from CF but the Webservice not accept it.

I tried

```
<cfset client = arraynew[]>
<cfset client[1] = structnew()>
<cfset client[1].apPat = "Estrada">
<cfset client[1].apMat = "Castillo">
```

this is my real code

```
<cfset arrAgente[1] = {}>
<cfset arrAgente[1].ramoTecnico = "1">
<cfset arrAgente[1].codAgente = "5095">

<cfset emissionRequest = {}>
<cfset emissionRequest.ramoTecnico = "1">
<cfset emissionRequest.codAgente = "5095">
<cfset emissionRequest.poliza = {}>
<cfset emissionRequest.poliza.codTipoPoliza = "2">
<cfset emissionRequest.poliza.ramoComercial = "5">
<!--- here is where I have problems beacuse I need to send an array or a list. The above code I dont have problems, the Net recognize it like a single array the structures----->
<cfset emissionRequest.agente = #arrAgente#>
```

Comment: You need to give more information. What do you mean by "WS not accept it"? Did it error? What was the error? What was it about the data structure the WS didn't seem to like? We're not, I'm afraid, telepathic: you need to provide us all the requisite info to be able to help you. Suggested reading: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: `<cfset client = arraynew[]>` is not valid CFML.  It should either be `<cfset client = arraynew(1)>` or `<cfset client = []>`... bearing in mind @AdamCameron's point that 'client' is used as a scope

Comment: Heh, good spot, Dunc.

Comment: Sorry Adam. Ws = webservice

I put client variable for the sample but in reality this is my code
    
 With this part is where I have problems. The Net not recognize like array of array

    <cfset arrAgente[1] = {}>
    <cfset arrAgente[1].ramoTecnico = "1">
    <cfset arrAgente[1].codAgente = "5095">

Comment: For example ths is the structure that I have to send
emissionrequest
   emissionrequest.var1 = 1
   emissionrequest.var2 = 2
   emissionrequest.poliza.codtipopoliza = 2
   emissionrequest.poliza.ramocomercial = 5
   --- array or list of agente and this is the problem ----
      emissionrequest.agente[1].ramotecnico = 1
      emissionrequest.agente[1].codagente = 5095

Comment: check it  [link]http://75.103.97.73/wsrest/array-sample.cfm

Answer (score 4):

`client` is a scope in CFML, so I doubt you can write to it like that. Use a different variable name ("client" is not a very descriptive variable name in the first place, anyhow).

Docs: "[Scope types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html)"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but a quick [search tells me](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) that `array(array())` creates a multi-dimensional array in PHP. And in the comments you mention (I think) needing a multi-dimensional array - *The Net not recognize like array of array ...* If that is the case then you need to create a multi-dimensional array in ColdFusion. You do that like this ([reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7ff8.html)):

```
<cfset arrAgente = ArrayNew(2) />
```

So you might try something like this:

```
<cfset arrAgente = ArrayNew(2) />
<cfset strAgente = StructNew() />

<cfset strAgente.apPat = "Estrada">
<cfset strAgente.apMat = "Castillo">
<cfset arrAgente[1][1] = strAgente />
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

If case matters (notice that gives you ALL CAPS for the index names) then try it this way which preserves the case you give it:

```
<cfset arrAgente = ArrayNew(2) />
<cfset strAgente = StructNew() />

<cfset rv = StructInsert(strAgente,"apPat","Estrada") />
<cfset rv = StructInsert(strAgente,"apMat","Castillo") />
<cfset arrAgente[1][1] = strAgente />
```

Which gives you this:

[image]